# RPIO Module installation

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio, raspbian-wheezy, modules

I've been trying to install the RPIO module onto my pi. so far, no luck because my pi is without internet at the moment (I only have internet on my laptop through mobile tethering). Does anybody know if there is a copy of raspbian wheezy with the RPIO module already installed?
If so, post a link in the answers/comments, or upload a link to the file on here.

Comment: One would still need the internet to download any link provided. How does a link help get around the no internet problem?

Comment: Pi has no internet connection. But my laptop is connected to my smartphone, using it as a hotspot!

Comment: Then the house is not without Internet, The Pi is. Why not tether the Pi to the laptop or phone? Or take the Pi to a friend's house who has internet access.

Comment: Because I'm unsure of how to do that with an Ethernet cable, and I don't have a dongle. The problem is resolved now anyway, but thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

No, RPIO.GPIO is not installed by default in the Raspbian or raspberrypi.org images.

You will need to install from the [github](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO).

**EDITED TO ADD**

If you have access to the internet just download https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/archive/master.zip and copy it to the Pi SD card.  If you have to use Windows put the SD card in a card reader.  The boot partition should be visible.  Copy master.zip to the boot partition (normal copy) then place the card back into the Pi and reboot.  Copy master.zip from /boot to where you want it.  Remember to delete the copy in /boot to save space.  Follow the github instructions to install RPIO.

Note that installation requires a few not installed by default packages such as python-dev.

Comment: would downloading a file from here (http://metachris.github.io/rpio/download/latest/) and running it through disk imager onto my SD card work?

Comment: @SamMason edited answer.

Answer (score -2):

Without an internet connection installation is a bit more difficult, but still possible. The package can be found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPIO

Near the bottom of the page is all of the recent versions.

Installation of a downloaded package can be done with `easy_install`

Comment: RPi.GPIO is not what Im after. I'm looking for RPIO. Which gives you advance settings, including interrupts (Which is what I'm after). the newest edition of Wheezy has RPi.GPIO if you're looking for 'startx'

Comment: @SamMason oh crap, read your question wrong

Comment: Haha, never mind. I will need an internet connection on my pi fot this won't I? at this moment, I'm on my mobile data. and will probably go to the library tomorrow if I can download it to my laptop!

Comment: @SamMason edited with link to package for offline install.

Comment: You're a legend!!! now I can pass my GCSE with ease

Comment: Here is a link for installing downloaded .egg packages manually. https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html Problem is, that you need `easy_install` which may or may not be included on your Pi already, there just isn't any other ways that I know of.